# Is the tour encouraging users to gloss over guidelines when asking questions?

Tags: support, asking-questions, statistics, tour-page

The tour is a rather prevalent page to reach, by design. It is the first item in the help menu:

[image]

Further, if you make it past that to the actual "Help Center", the entire top section is a plug for the tour, again.

[image]

This is all to say that the tour gets a lot of attention. However, the tour itself is very visually pleasing and as a result that lends to easily reading the headings only, which are (in order):

- Ask questions, get answers, no distractions
- Get answers to practical, detailed questions
- Tags make it easy to find interesting questions
- You earn reputation when people vote on your posts
- Improve posts by editing or commenting
- Unlock badges for special achievements
- **Find a question to answer, or ask your own**

And then there is a button to ask a question. Given that none of the tour has addressed the topicality of Stack Overflow questions, the scope of a typical question, providing an example to work with, or *any* of the guidance we (or at least I) am wondering how users miss: **are the questions that result from this "Ask Question" button the bottom of the barrel**?

Comment: This is more [discussion] than [support].

Comment: @StephenLeppik - Perhaps that would be the case if this question was based in conjecture, but I was strongly hoping to get some statistics on this situation. As such, I had asked in the Tavern at MSE to sort of see if this was something that was possible. "I can probably get some rough stats on that / Post meta question", [Shog9 told me](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5423035#5423035). This is why it is tagged as support, because it is about numbers rather than guesswork. We can dissect numbers later, if present.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Short answer:** no, they're not the bottom of the barrel. They're not the top either.

### Longer answer...

We got this nifty little event tracker we use internally. Lets us do things like this:

[image: image of event tracker]

That's roughly a month's worth of data, and indicates that - of the 134K sessions that viewed the Tour - not quite 9% clicked that button, and of those just shy of 60% went on to post a question. So, a few hundred questions a day.

Now...

#### How many of these are half-way *decent?*

Well, let's pick an arbitrary definition for that. I like, "Not closed, not deleted, attracted at least one answer, and scores >= 0".

Out of those questions, 42% fall into that category, a hair over 2K in the last month.

For contrast:

- about 45% of *all* questions asked in the last month fit that criteria
- not quite 41% of questions asked after viewing /help/on-topic fit that criteria.
- a bit less than 39% of questions asked after viewing /help/how-to-ask fit that criteria.
- over 47% of questions asked after viewing /help/mcve fit that criteria. Unfortunately, we only got 718 of these last month.

Comment: This is really in depth, thanks! Apparently anyone willing to attempt at reading the support material is doing better than the average question asker, or at least that was my impression. The spike for the mcve page is interesting, and overall just the organization of data you guys collect is really well done.

Comment: I was right in the middle of writing a SEDE query to find this answer.

Comment: See revision please, @Travis: was counting answers (which makes me wonder about that event tracker a bit, but...)

Comment: How the data comes out if we remove the "have attracted at least 1 answer" criteria? I would expect that people with tougher questions are more likely to document themselves before asking anyways, and how do this compare against the big ask button (I know you included an "all", but you know)?

Comment: Thanks for the revision, while the numbers did change, the relations didn't change all that much. It still seems like there is not a significant distance between the average question posted and those from the tour (which was the premise I was curious about). While this does show they are apparently slightly below average, that could perhaps just be from this set and not a broader trend. The most interesting facet here to me is still the mcve result when compared with other help pages. Overall, still very informative.

Comment: Goes up by 20-30 %age points, @Braiam.