# Make the search bar in meta also search the help center

Tags: feature-request, search, meta, help-center

The prominence of the new search bar is going to override the ability to search in the help center as seen below.

[image]

---

Most users finding their way to help are going to end up searching in the wrong bar. If the argument is that new users don't even know to click on the help center, how can they then be expected to know which search bar to use here? They cannot.

Moreover, if there is a desire to remove the help icon (as stated by staff) then it only seems rational to actually include the help in the search results for meta.

Searching for banned in the meta search bar should return the 3 results from the help center, for example.

[image]

This should not be complicated to implement. Meta searches are much lighter weight than the main searchers are, and as a result should easily have room to issue a simultaneous search that pairs these two results. Simply prepend the help center results to the meta results. As the help center is already rather narrow in scope, this will never be a large impact and should be the source material returned when there is a match anyway.

It would look like this:

[image]

While it may not seem terribly important to do this because hand waving, it is very important to allow new users the opportunity to find these help files. It has been [statistically shown that users who view the MCVE help page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/337960/1026459) for example are more likely to ask a question which stands the test of time.

**Allow the meta search bar to include help center results.**

Comment: "meta search bar" Did you mean: ***search bars on both meta and main sites***

Comment: No, he meant meta. If you read the post, you can see very clearly he is referring ***exclusively*** to SO Meta

Comment: Just to clarify, *only* the search bar on SO Meta. Just as @Dev says as well.

Comment: @dorukayhan Making the search bar on Stack Overflow proper search through the help center wouldn't make much sense, because the help center doesn't contain very many solutions to programming problems. Making the search bar on Stack Overflow meta search the help center _would_ make a lot of sense, because many answers to common meta questions can be found in the help center.

Comment: @TinyGiant But most new users (i.e users who didn't take a look at the help center yet) aren't even aware of Meta's existence, so they wouldn't use the meta search bar. If everyone knew that there's this thing called "Meta Stack Overflow" then the tag [stack-overflow](//stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stack-overflow) wouldn't have an all-caps warning in its excerpt telling that questions about SO belong to Meta.

Comment: @dorukayhan: Presumably, the people who are actually seeing this search bar will know that Meta exists.  They're here.

Comment: @dorukayhan we can't fix everything. Including the Stack Overflow proper search in this would do more harm than good I think.

Comment: Can you share the script you used to change the color and styling of your bar?

Comment: @TotZam - Sure. Here it is [on GitHub](https://github.com/travisjj/StackTop/tree/master), and here it is as a [free chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stacktop/cojbkkhojpefjbiobkabibjaedocpjhn?hl=en-US&gl=US)

Comment: @TravisJ Thanks! I like how you also shortened Documentation to Docs to save space. I was able to use your script as a base to learn how to create my own, and then added additional changes like making the entire top-bar, as well as the search-bar, slightly shorter.