# Is there any insight into comments flagged or deleted against the reputation of the commentator when making said comment?

Tags: discussion, comments, statistics

I'm mulling a feature request (which is a feature request buried in another discussion somewhere here on Meta), but would like to know some data.

**For each reputation band with the privilege of commenting, what is the correlation between reputation and amount of deleted comments, and what types of comment flags does this reputation band skew towards?**

Effectively, I'm looking for any data which can support or disprove these hypotheses:

- Users with lower reputation tend to earn more comment flags, which results in the comment being deleted.
- Users with lower reputation tend to have their comments flagged as being rude or abusive.
- Users with higher reputation tend to earn more comment flags.
- Users with higher reputation tend to have their comments flagged as being rude or abusive.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ:  You can't really get the information I want from SEDE.  This includes things like deleted comments, and there's only 7 million *visible* comments on the site.

Comment: Thus your statement _"Effectively, I'm looking for any data which can support or disprove these hypotheses"_ looks a bit futile. If mods can extract that information that will live at their realm. If a mean mortal cannot, that information is probably not being disclosed for us.

Comment: Employees have access to some of the statistics I want.  Not sure if they can get them *all*, but they can at least get more than I could as a layman.  Not sure how it appears futile @πάνταῥεῖ; they've fulfilled requests like this in the past.

Comment: Sure, but you're _mulling_ for a _feature request_ beyond privileges that might probably not applied for _mere mortals_ as we are.

Comment: Not clear how you arrived at that @πάνταῥεῖ.  I'm looking for facts to support or refute arguments in my feature request, and I can't get those facts without the ability to see deleted comments.  That's all there is to this, really.

Comment: I don't think that reputation is going to correlate to comment deletion. I think that comment deletion correlates to more comment deletion though, and if users are having their comments deleted at high rates then they should be throttled.

Comment: @TravisJ:  That's kind of what I want to figure out.  To take the training wheels off - is there a difference between users who *just* figure out they can comment everywhere and how often their comments are flagged (and thus removed), versus someone like you or me who has a few winters under our belt and have our comments flagged (and thus removed)?  That information could *then* be used as a basis to justify/reject if throttling would even be effective at all.

Comment: There's a third class of accounts that might play into these numbers: deleted accounts. Many of the most abusive new accounts simply get deleted, and some highly abusive users create account after account to evade bans and be rude to people. There have also been some higher-reputation users who deleted their accounts after being repeatedly warned about abusive behavior. Unfortunately, you probably won't have pre-deletion reputation levels, but I bet deleted accounts would have a disproportionate number of flagged comments and might be an interesting point of comparison.

Comment: @BradLarson:  That's an interesting point.  I do wonder if the high-rep users who actually go through that effort is more an outlier than a signal, but would be interesting to see; I do agree there.

Comment: I have no idea how many of my comments are flagged rude/abusive — I trust the number is small, but I'm not sure how I'd find out.  Some of my comments are substantive (almost, but not quite answers — and I'm usually not motivated to convert the comment into an answer for any of a number of reasons, laziness being one frequent one).  Many are requests for clarification or improvement.  I remove many of those after the question or answer is improved.  Some I don't get around to removing; some of those could be flagged 'no longer needed'. _[…continued…]_

Comment: _[…continuation…]_ I know I flag quite a lot of comments by other people as 'no longer needed' when I revisit a Q&A after some years; I remove my own comments if they're no longer needed, and flag other people's too. I also quite often have sequences of comments (as here) that are connected. I wouldn't delete one without also deleting the other; should that be counted as one or two comments, though? It's undoubtedly easier to treat this as two comments, but it is in many ways one comment extended over a couple of 'comment limit' units. It'd be interesting to see the analysis; it won't be easy.

Comment: I think that for this one we need to run to the roof and turn on the Shog-Signal.

Comment: @yivi in fact, I'm on the edge of my seat waiting for the fat tables and graphs to appear.

Comment: @yivi I did just that.

Comment: @Braiam:  Not a support question because I'm not asking on how to use the site (this fits nicely into the gray, mushy area of a dicussion).

Comment: By "earn more comment flags" do you mean increase the number of flags they have available to cast by successfully flagging comments themselves, or do you mean they tend to have more of their own comments flagged by others?

Comment: The latter @TylerH.

Comment: @Makoto Shog seems to be more responsive of support request (ie. when he isn't the one that comes forward to provide the data) https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsupport%5D+%5Bstats%5D+user%3A811 also, some reasoning here https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/337957/is-the-tour-encouraging-users-to-gloss-over-guidelines-when-asking-questions/337960#comment412697_337957

Comment: I've personally had success with this posted as a discussion, @Braiam.  But let's not fuss over the color of the bike shed, shall we?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - Honestly, the situation you describe shouldn't trigger any sort of recividism system put in place for comments. I am assuming it would include a time range, and also heavily weigh the type of comment deletion; this would easily clear your activity. Cleaning up shouldn't be confused with abusing the system.